# net.tcp service works when hosted by Net.Tcp Listener Adapter, but not Windows Service

Tags: wcf, windows-services, net.tcp

I created a WCF net.tcp service and hosted it using the Net.Tcp Listener Adapter, and it works great - I have some messaging set up on the callback so the service updates the client with the status. Now, I'm trying to get it to work by being hosted via a Windows Service, and all I'm doing is creating a ServiceHost using the same class that the original uses:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using BuilderService;

namespace BuilderWindowsService
{
    public class BuilderWindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceHost ServiceHost = null;
        public BuilderWindowsService()
        {
            ServiceName = ServiceNames.Builder;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Run(new BuilderWindowsService());
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (ServiceHost != null)
                ServiceHost.Close();
            ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Builder));
            ServiceHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if(ServiceHost != null)
            {
                ServiceHost.Close();
                ServiceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can connect to the service and send a request, but it never responds nor times out. I know I'm hitting the Windows Service because I have it on another port (8002), and I can add it as a reference using that.

My App.config for the Windows Service is pretty much identical to the Web.config of the original too. Same thing for the client I am using, except it is pointing to the 8002 endpoint instead of 808. Also, I already have this working for another service, doing the exact same setup, but for some reason this one never responds.

**UPDATE**

I created a little client app to test out directly hitting the windows service to rule out anything interfering, and it generated the following app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IBuilder" 
                         closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                         openTimeout="00:01:00"
                         receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                         sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                         transactionFlow="false" 
                         transferMode="Buffered"
                         transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
                         listenBacklog="10"
                         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                         maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                         maxConnections="10"
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                                  maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                                  maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                                  maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                                  maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" 
                                     inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                                     enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                                   protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                                 algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8002/BuilderService/Builder.svc"
                      binding="netTcpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IBuilder"
                      contract="RGBRef.IBuilder" 
                      name="NetTcpBinding_IBuilder">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Which looks pretty normal to me (note: I manually upped the buffer/string length values to the maximum). Only things that are different from my original config:

```
transferMode="Buffered"
transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
listenBacklog="10"
<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
           protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
```

Not sure if the service is expecting those or something. Either way, it's still not getting any response back, nor an error.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the service is faulting since it now runs under different credentials as a Windows Service. Write some EventLog entries to trace where the fault is occurring. I don't believe is the callback, I suspect it's something else in the service failing.

Comment: added logging to the windows service, but it doesn't error anywhere